# How to make a query of the max month/year of a group of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't really know how to make a MySQL query where I get all the data(Columns) of the most present month + year.

Being a little bit more specific I need to group the columns (description, data1, data2, data3) and only get the one that has the highest month +  year.

The table contains data like this one:

```
description     data1   data2   data3   year    month   adddate
desc1           0       7       1       2019    5       2019-05-23
desc2           0       7       1       2019    5       2019-05-23
desc3           1       7       1       2019    5       2019-05-23
desc4           0       2       1       2018    12      2019-05-23
```

I've tried using max on the month, year and adddate.

```
select description, data1, data2, data3, max(year) as year, max(month) as month, max(adddate) as adddate
            from tabledata
            group by description, data1, data2, data3
```

But with this I'm getting that the max register is desc2 with the month 12 which is not correct since the month is desc2 is 6.

Comment: So what is your expected result? You have 3 rows with the most recent year/month. Do you want these 3 rows?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the max value of an expression like:

```
100 * year + month
```

or

```
12 * year + month
```

So do this:

```
select *
from tabledata
where 100 * year + month = (
  select max(100 * year + month)
  from tabledata
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2e01cb7bdf4d76b3ed7eaa4693693aee).
Results:

```
> description | data1 | data2 | data3 | year | month | adddate            
> :---------- | ----: | ----: | ----: | ---: | ----: | :---------
> desc1       |     0 |     7 |     1 | 2019 |     5 | 23/05/2019
> desc2       |     0 |     7 |     1 | 2019 |     5 | 23/05/2019
> desc3       |     1 |     7 |     1 | 2019 |     5 | 23/05/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the max combination of year and month (MaxYearMonth) and then join to your table again to find all the rows that match that MaxYearMonth. Here is the solution for SQL Server...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tabledata', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tabledata; 

CREATE TABLE #tabledata
(
    description VARCHAR(10)
  , data1 INT
  , data2 INT
  , data3 INT
  , year INT
  , month INT
  , adddate DATE
);

INSERT INTO #tabledata VALUES ('desc1', 0, 7, 1, 2019, 5, '2019-05-23')
INSERT INTO #tabledata VALUES ('desc2', 0, 7, 1, 2019, 5, '2019-05-23')
INSERT INTO #tabledata VALUES ('desc3', 1, 7, 1, 2019, 5, '2019-05-23')
INSERT INTO #tabledata VALUES ('desc4', 0, 2, 1, 2018, 12, '2019-05-23')

select a.description, a.data1, a.data2, a.data3
from #tabledata a 
inner join 
(
   select max(convert(char(4), year) + right('0' + convert(varchar(2), month), 2)) as [MaxYearMonth]
   from #tabledata
) b on convert(char(4), a.year) + right('0' + convert(varchar(2), a.month), 2) = b.MaxYearMonth
```

Yields this...

```
description data1       data2       data3
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
desc1       0           7           1
desc2       0           7           1
desc3       1           7           1
```

Click [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42ad5b4951f07b66a4806ec123740c3f) to see it in action.

You mention "mysql" so if you are really using mySQL then the syntax will likely need to change a bit.

Comment: What im getting with this is:

```
select a.description, a.data1, a.data2, a.data3, a.month, a.year
from tabledata a 
inner join 
(
   select max(convert(char(4), year) + right('0' + convert(varchar(2), month), 2)) as [MaxYearMonth]
   from tabledata
   where   (data1=3)
   and (data2=0)
) b on convert(char(4), a.year) + right('0' + convert(varchar(2), a.month), 2) = b.MaxYearMonth
```
All 3 registers have same description, month and year, wich is not correct, they are all different

Comment: I edited my answer with fully functional sample (dbfiddle link included). You didn't address the "mysql" in your question as opposed to your "sql-server" tag. You can't have both. Which is it?